# Jquery: How can I make a figure element collapsible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make a figure element collapsible, without adding an extra button?

```html
<figure><img src="abc.png"></figure>
```

By default, I would like to place a button to open the image at this point. Can this button be generated automatically?

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ht6soL80/) ? You said `without adding an extra button` but then you say `I would like to place a button to open the image` what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `slideToggle()` function assuming you have jQuery included (HIGHLY RECOMMEND).

Then you can simply do:

```
$( "#myButton" ).click(function() {
  $( "figure" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

You will need to of course add a button. You could append one with jQUery (automatically) or you can edit the HTML to get it there.

Here is the HTML way

```
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```

Here is the jQuery way (untested)

```
$('figure').append("<button id='myButton'>Click Me</button>");
```

Best of Luck to You! (again this is all untested)

Come to think of it you probably want `after()` instead of `append()`
because your button will disappear after you toggle once.
Use this

```
$('figure').after("<button id='myButton'>Click Me</button>");
```

Link to jQuery slideToggle: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: There is also `toggleClass` which could be used to toggle a class such as `hidden` from bootstrap or custom css.

Comment: This would work though you wouldn't have the animation effect `slideToggle()` provides. You could use CSS Animations as well to get any desired effect however. Or you could also use jQuery animate as well. @GetOffMyLawn

Comment: You would have it if you used css transitions, which run smoother than jquery's transitions, but you also lose lots of easing effects if that is important to what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this simple code snippet to toggle image using figure element itself

```js
$('#accordian_img').click(function () {
    $('.img-toggle').toggleClass("show"); // toggle show class to image element
});
```

```css
/* Image style to show and hide */
.img-toggle.show {
  display:block;
}
.img-toggle {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<figure id="accordian_img" style="width:400px;cursor:pointer">
  Click To Toggle Image 
  <img class="img-toggle" src="http://placehold.it/400x150">
</figure>
```